What does "python3 -t" do?
$ python3 -t -c 'print("hello world")'
hello world

What does -t do? It's not mentioned in python3 --help.
Usually unknown options cause a non-zero exit code, like
$ python3 -r
Unknown option: -r
usage: python3 [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.


I would guess it's a leftover from Python 2. Can't test now of it works the same.

The -t option in python3 was a feature from Python 2.x that warned about inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in the source code. However, this option was removed in Python 3.x.
Therefore, when you run python3 -t -c 'print("hello world")', Python 3 just ignores the -t option and executes the code as usual.

To clarify, removed in the sense that the error (rather than warning) version -tt became the default behavior.

If it doesn't actually do anything, why didn't they remove it when they removed other options such as -U in Python 3.0?

The -t option might have been left in for backward compatibility or because it didn't conflict with any new features or cause any issues.

@nosteponsnek: This is just a guess, but -U was already an “option you shouldn’t use” and -tt was a prevalent good idea, so maybe the backward compatibility value was judged to be different.
